# Disable Keep Alive in Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, apache, keep-alive, apache-commons-httpclient

For some problem that we couldn't solve, I want to disable keep alive on Apache HttpClient 3.1. However, I couldn't find any resource on the Internet for that. Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable HTTP 1.1 support on you method, i.e. `httpMethod.setHttp11(false);` but you will lost some other features.

You can also try to force the connection header to ask the server to close the connection after its response: `httpMethod.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close")`.