# Is keep-alive always sent in requests using httpclient and how to prevent sending it

Tags: java, spring, httpclient, keep-alive

I have a Java/Spring project where I am using Oauth2RestTemplate and making it use HttpClient (org.apache.http.client.Httpclient) instead of the default SimpleClient

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory).build(); 

HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
oAuth2RestTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
```

With respect to this, I wanted to know/understand if the keep-alive header is always sent for all the requests?

If it is always sent, is there a way to disable sending it? I see a post - [Disable Keep Alive in Apache HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807691/disable-keep-alive-in-apache-httpclient) that talks about disabling it but it proposes a setting on httpMethod. I am not sure how to get access to this httpMethod in my code setup I described above.

Comment: @Andreas From the method signatures I think the OP is using the Apache http client, not Java 11 http client.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implement a `ConnectionReuseStrategy` with a `keepAlive()` method that simply returns false. See `setConnectionReuseStrategy()` in `HttpClientBuilder`.

You may also want to send a `Connection` header with the value of `close`.

https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/ConnectionReuseStrategy.html

Example:

```java
List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<>();
headers.add(new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.CONNECTION, "close"));
HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultHeaders(headers)
  .setConnectionReuseStrategy(
    new ConnectionReuseStrategy() {
      @Override
      public boolean keepAlive(HttpResponse httpResponse, HttpContext httpContext) {
        log.info("**** keepAlive strategy returning false");
        return false;
      }
});
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = builder.build();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://google.com");
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
log.info("Response status: " + response.getStatusLine());
response.close();
```

Some additional information:

**1. The Keep-Alive header**

When most people say `keep-alive` header, they usually mean a different header called `Connection`.  The two headers work together:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=1000
...
```

The `Connection` header is a hint that the connection should be re-used. The `Keep-Alive` header specifies the minimum amount of time the connection should remain open, and the maximum number of requests the connection may be re-used for.

Common values for the `Connection` header are `keep-alive` and `close`.  Both the server and the client can send this header.  If the `Connection` header is set to `close`, the `Keep-Alive` header is ignored.

**2. HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2**

With HTTP/1.1, connections are persistent by default.  The `Keep-Alive` header was deprecated (no longer defined in the HTTP specification), although many servers still send them for backwards compatibility.

Clients which cannot handle HTTP/1.1 persistent connections should set a `Connection` header with the value `close`.

HTTP/2 uses multiplexing; neither the `Connection` nor the `Keep-Alive` header should be used with HTTP/2.

**3. Effect of proxies and caches**

Generally speaking, persistent connections do not work through non-transparent proxies.  They will silently drop any `Connection` or `Keep-Alive` headers.

**4. Connection handling**

Since persistent connections are now the default with HTTP/1.1, we need a mechanism to control when/how they are used.  With the Apache http client, the `ConnectionReuseStrategy` determines whether or not the connection should be persistent, while the `ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy` specifies the maximum idle time for a connection to be re-usable.

Comment: I tried setting it as:
HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory).setConnectionReuseStrategy(connectionReuseStrategy).build(); 

ConnectionReuseStrategy connectionReuseStrategy = new ConnectionReuseStrategy() {
   @Override
   public boolean keepAlive(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) {
     System.out.println("in connectionReuseStrategy **************");
     return false;
   }
};
I am not sure how to test if this really works. Also, the print statement above is not getting printed

Comment: Hmm, not sure why it's not getting called.  I just added an example (above) which gets called at least once with each execute().  But what are you trying to solve specifically?  In your original post you mentioned preventing the client from sending a keep-alive header, but the http keep-alive _header_ (specifically) is really sent by the server (not by the client) and is actually deprecated behavior in HTTP/1.1 -- replaced by persistent connections.

Comment: So, now, as I understand, keep-live is sent only in the response from the server. what does overriding keepAlive method to return false exactly do? 
Will it prevent the keep-alive from being returned in the response?
Or keep-alive will still be returned in response, overriding will just close the connection inspite of seeing keep-alive? I am trying to understand how it works

Comment: I misspoke a bit, technically a client can send the keep-alive header.  But usually what you want to send to _prevent_ keep-alives is a different header called `Connection`.  I've updated the answer with a bit more info, hope that helps clarifies the issue.

Comment: Would your answer of setting connectionReusestrategy (with keepAlive overridden to return false) prevent sending connection `Connection: Keep-Alive`? I still see it sent though inspite of using connectionReuseStrategy

Comment: No, but that shouldn't matter since connections will not be reused per connection strategy.  However it's possible to set the Connection header to `close` as default (see updated example for syntax).

Comment: @peekay I do see a few more default headers in addition to **Connection** being added by HttpClient by **default** such as "host", "via", "x-forwarded-for" and "cache-control". How do we go about handling these? Do proxies play a role in these?